# React-redux state updates but component does not rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, rerender

There like hundreds of questions about this topic but nothing worked for me.

[image: Component does not rerender]

As you can see in the picture above that the state is obviously updating by `this.props.getSubcontractors();` in 
containers/SubcontractorListPage.js `componentWillMount()` function. But the viewComponent SubcontractorList.js does not rerender on Props change. There is a blank page.

### containers/SubcontractorListPage.js

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import SubcontractorList from 
'../components/viewComponents/SubcontractorList/SubcontractorList';
import * as SubcontractorActions from '../actions/subcontractor';

class SubcontractorListPage extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    getSubcontractors: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    subcontractor: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    console.log(this.props);
    this.props.getSubcontractors();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <SubcontractorList subcontractors=
      {this.props.subcontractor.subcontractors} />
    );
  }
}

export default connect(
  state => ({ subcontractor: state.subcontractor }),
  dispatch => bindActionCreators(SubcontractorActions, dispatch)
)(SubcontractorListPage);
```

### components/viewComponents/SubcontractorList/SubcontractorList.js

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import styles from './SubcontractorList.scss';

class SubcontractorList extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    subcontractors: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  };

  render() {
    const subcontractors = this.props.subcontractors;

    let display = <div />;
    console.log(subcontractors);

    display = (
      <div className={styles.Breadcrumb}>
        {subcontractors.map((item) =>
          <div className={styles.Item} key={item.Id}>
            {item.Name}lol</div>
        )}
      </div>
    );

    return display;
  }
}

export default SubcontractorList;
```

### actions/subcontractor.js

```
export const SUBCONTRACTORS_GET = 'SUBCONTRACTORS_GET';
export const SUBCONTRACTOR_GET = 'SUBCONTRACTOR_GET';
export const SUBCONTRACTOR_ADD = 'SUBCONTRACTOR_ADD';
export const SUBCONTRACTOR_EDIT = 'SUBCONTRACTOR_EDIT';
export const SUBCONTRACTOR_DELETE = 'SUBCONTRACTOR_DELETE';

export function getSubcontractors() {
  return {
    type: SUBCONTRACTORS_GET
  };
}

export function getSubcontractor() {
  return {
    type: SUBCONTRACTOR_GET
  };
}
```

### reducers/subcontractor.js

```
import { SUBCONTRACTORS_GET, SUBCONTRACTOR_GET } from         
'../actions/subcontractor';

import getTable from '../utils/dbHelper/getTable';

const initialState = {
  subcontractors: [],
  subcontractor: {}
};

export type subcontractorStateType = {
  subcontractors: [],
  subcontractor: {}
};

type actionType = {
  type: string
};

export default function subcontractor(state: {} = initialState, 
action: actionType) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SUBCONTRACTORS_GET:
      return {
        ...state,
        subcontractors: getTable('SUBCONTRACTOR')
      };
    case SUBCONTRACTOR_GET:
      console.log('SUBCONTRACTORS_GET');
      break;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**How to resolve this?**

### Update

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();

const dbSrc = '../testdb';

export default function getTable(tablename) {
  const db = new sqlite3.Database(dbSrc);
  const queries = [];
  db.each(`SELECT * FROM ${tablename}`, (err, row) => {
    queries.push(row);
    console.log(row);
  });

  db.close();
  return queries;
}
```

Comment: What does the `getTable` util method look like?

Comment: A function that gets data from a sqlite file. I added it to the post.

Comment: Now I'm pretty confused.  That DB code won't run in a browser.  Is this being server-rendered?

Comment: I am using this Boilerplate: https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate

Comment: Okay.  As a side note not directly part of your question: you shouldn't be doing database access in a reducer.  Your action creator should be doing that (probably in a thunk), and dispatching an action with the result of the query.

Comment: Okay thanks for that. But this is probably not the problem?

Comment: Probably not.  To be honest, I'm a bit confused - you're saying that the `console.log()` statement in your component is showing the updated values, but the component is not rendering them?

Comment: Yes. The console.log() shows that there are two entries in the array. But the render method does not rerender these elements. When I had something manually a div or sth like that and save, the hot mod reloading renders and the two array elements are shown up.